# Android EditText adding border to text

Tags: android

I am working on an android application where I need to create an edit text in which when user types it will output outlined text, the ondraw method of my custom edittext looks like this

```
TextPaint paint = this.getPaint();
paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
this.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffffff"));
super.onDraw(canvas);
paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeJoin(strokeJoin);
paint.setStrokeMiter(strokeMiter);
paint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
this.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff000000"));
super.onDraw(canvas);`
```

This is supposed to show white text with black outline, but this only shows the black outline and the text is not filled, if I implement the same method in TextView it works just fine but does not work for EditText.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: where is your code to set color for editText?

Comment: `this.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffffff"));` this line does exactly that

Comment: use #ffffff rather than #ffffffff because more than 6 characters in color selection are automatically discarded and the resultant color becomes undesirable!

Comment: that is ARGB value and not RGB :), it is not discarded.